# Accessibility Voiceover reads out semantic version patch without 'dot'

Tags: ios, accessibility

when given a semantic version number like 1.2.3 
iOS Accessibility reads it out like 'one dot two three' instead of 'one dot two dot three'

this happens in html (like terms and conditions) and in labels also.

Is there a way to make it read out correctly? 
using xcode 7.2.x.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is related to user-specific VoiceOver preferences - you can customize things like how verbose the screenreader is, whether it announces repeated punctuation, etc.

If you want to try and force it to read a certain way, at least in HTML, you could wrap the number in a span with an aria-label attribute, which will override the contents:

```
<span aria-label="one dot two dot three">1.2.3</span>
```

or

```
<span aria-label="one point two point three">1.2.3</span>
```

for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however looks like the voiceover in iOS does not honor aria-label or aria-labelledby. it still reads out without the dots

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... If Jack's answer doesn't work, you might want to confirm what version of iOS you are testing Voice Over with. But it could very well be that aria-label isn't supported in this fashion for VoiceOver, since it's original purpose was originally for input fields or buttons where actual physical labels didn't exist (not spans or divs).

http://modernaccessibility.com/forum/topic/voiceover-ios-html4-html5-wai-aria-accessibility-support/ mentions support in 9.1 and it seems like it has been in for a bit but I could see bugs come into play. The listing could possibly be incorrect or the support of aria-label on spans in VoiceOver is not supported so you might try alternatives as well.

If aria-hidden is working right this should be read as desired:

```
<span aria-hidden="true">1.2.3</span> <span class="visuallyhidden">one dot two dot three</span>
```

or

```
<span>1.2<span class="visuallyhidden">dot</span><span class="addDotInBeforePseudoElement">3</span>
```

or maybe treat it with aria-describedby to better explain semantic versions

```
<span aria-describedby="helperText">1.2.3</span>
<p id="helperText" class="visuallyhidden">Major version 1 - Minor version 2 - Patch version 3</p>
```

CSS

```
.visuallyhidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
.addDotInBeforePseudoElement:before {
  content: ".";
}
```

Side note:

From looking here there have been other screen readers that didn't support aria-label on divs / spans in earlier versions (e.g. NVDA)
https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/1354

Comment: tried your above suggestions on iOS 9.3, but still no luck

first suggestion displays 1.2.3one dot two dot three
second displays : 1.2dot3 1.2.3
third displays - Major version 1 - Minor version 2 - Patch version 3

Comment: I should have clarified the CSS for you. i used naming for classes to clarify approaches but can give you the CSS syntax to make those classes valuable... And now updated with visually hidden css